# zip/tar/? files with depth parameter

Tags: linux, compression, zip, tar

I would like to zip files from a directory but only to a given depth. In the example below I would like to include files until a depth of 3:

```
dir0/
 dir1/
     dir2 -> subdir1, subdir2
     dir3 ->
     file1
```

If I could issue:

```
zip --depth 3 -r output dir0
```

I would have the following output:

```
dir0/dir1/file1
```

How can I achieve this? Should I use tar, or is there any other common tool in Linux?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `find` with `-maxdepth` to limit the traversal depth, then use the tool's option to take filenames from stdin, or xargs or command substitution.

```
find ... -maxdepth 3 ... | zip -@ ...
```